# Validation Rule in Apex Trigger not working as expected

Tags: apex, trigger, validation

I have created an Apex trigger to replace the many validation rules on one of our custom objects, all work as expected except one (I have left out all other validations to make the below code more manageable):

```
trigger Project_Validation on BPS_Projects__c (before insert, before update) {    

    public RecordType projImpInit = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'BPS_Projects__c' AND Name = 'Implementation Initiative' LIMIT 1];

    for(BPS_Projects__c myproj:trigger.new){
        if(myproj.RecordTypeId == projImpInit.Id){
            //**PROJECT STAGE CHANGED, VALIDATE STATUS CHECKBOX
            //**This validation ensures that when a user updates the Stage of a Project, 
            //   they also take into account the
            //Status field and update if required. After the Status field is checked, 
            //   the user needs to check the
            //"Status Validated" checkbox before the record can be saved.
            if(trigger.isUpdate){
                if(myproj.Project_Stage__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(myproj.Id).Project_Stage__c 
                   && 
                   myproj.Status_Validated__c == false){
                    myproj.Status_Validated__c.adderror('You changed the Project Stage. Please update the Project Status field if necessary, and when correct, check the "Status Validated" field.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, the comparison between the *old Stage* and *new Stage* isn't the problem as the error message shows when I update the **Project Stage** (picklist) field, and doesn't if I update any other field in my sandbox. However, it doesn't matter whether I check or leave the **Status Validated** (checkbox) field unchecked. The error shows in both cases.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be the case?

Thanks in advance!
Aaron

Comment: I'm sorry, I may not have been very clear in my question. What I want is:
When the user changes the Project Stage, they need to also select the Status Validated checkbox (to indicate that they have reviewed and updated the Status field if necessary).  Only if the Status Validated checkbox is Unchecked (False), should the error be displayed.

Comment: My bad I misread the question for my first comment, try adding brackets around the stage change check - `((myproj.Project_Stage__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(myproj.Id).Project_Stage__c) && myproj.Status_Validated__c == false)`

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue. It's something I did try earlier, and again just now, no dice.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue. The code as shown in the initial question is indeed correct, however a workflow rule was interfering by resetting the Status Validated checkbox (to false). So before the trigger could go through it's validations, the field was already reset, and therefore display the error.

Thank you Alex and Vigneshwaran for your input. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in your code. But very rarely i face this kind of issues with boolean(checkbox fields).

Instead of checking the boolean value to be false like this

```
if(myproj.Project_Stage__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(myproj.Id).Project_Stage__c && myproj.Status_Validated__c == false){
```

you can try using the boolean field itself like this

```
if(myproj.Project_Stage__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(myproj.Id).Project_Stage__c && !myproj.Status_Validated__c){
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While using `!booleanField` is  best practice, I'd be astonished if this would solve the issue.  Apex Boolean variables initialize as null, Sobject boolean fields initialize as false (unless there is a default value of true on the metadata)